# Union operation on sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading an example in a book that says: The union of $ \{ x\in \Bbb R\; | \; x \lt 5\} $ and $ \{ x\in \Bbb Z\; | \; x \lt 8\} $ is $\{ x\in \Bbb R\; | \; x \le 5, or\;x = 6\; or\; x = 7\} $

I don't understand the result particularly the or part. Why it can not be $\{ x\in \Bbb R\; | \; x \lt 8\} $ ?

Comment: Because the union only includes the _integers_ in $[5,8)$, but all the real numbers in $(-\infty,5)$.

Comment: Your suggested set includes $\frac{11}2$; the actual union does not.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb Z$.  Therein lies the key to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the $\color{red}{second \space set}$ $ \{ x\in \Bbb Z\; | \; x \lt 8\} $ is equal to $\color{red}{\{.....,-2,-3,-1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7\}}$ and so when you take the union of that with all reals numbers less than $\color{blue}{5}$ ($\color{blue}{first \space set}$) , You will get all $\color{blue}{real \space numbers  \space less \space  than}$ or $\color{red}{equal}$ to $\color{red}{5}$ plus $\color{red}{6}$ and $\color{red}{7}$

Comment: $\Bbb Z$ is the set of integers, so $\{x\in\Bbb Z\mid x<8\}=\{\cdots,-1,0,1,2,\cdots,7\}$.

Comment: @user26486 Yep, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: $\{x\in\Bbb Z\mid x<8\}$ _equals_ $\{\cdots,-1,0,1,2,\cdots,7\}$, but does not consist of it (which we would say if $\{x\in\Bbb Z\mid x<8\}$ had $\{\cdots,-1,0,1,2,\cdots,7\}$ as an element).

Comment: @user26486 I am saying consists not contains

Comment: I edited the comment. It's the same with 'consists'. The two sets are identical, so you can't say one is made up of another ([Oxford definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consist)).

Comment: @user26486 fair enough man

Comment: The set in blue is the first set.